# Simulating multiple server (MMC) queue using R programming

Tags: r, queue, simulation

I am trying to simulate a multiple server single queue model (MMC) using R programming. I have written one previously simulating a single server single queue model (MM1) but I have no idea how to change it to MMC model. Here is the code for the MM1 simulation:

```
lambda=2        #Arrival rate
mu=3            #Service rate
time = 0
simtime = 1000  #Simulation time
arrive = 0
service = 0 
s.start = 0     #Service start time
t.service = 0       #Total service time
s.end=0     #Service end time
complete=0

while(time<simtime){

service<-rexp(1,mu)

if(length(customer)==0){

  arrive<-rexp(1,lambda)
  s.start<-arrive
  customer<-customer+1

} else {

  arrive<-arrive+rexp(1,lambda)
  s.start<-max(arrive,s.end)
  customer<-customer+1

}

t.service<-t.service+service
s.end<-s.start+service    
time<-arrive

}
```

Can anybody offer some suggestions to change the code to account for multiple server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explicit what you want to achieve exactly and what are the idea you came up with so far...

Comment: Please also correct  MM1 code: for example,  `customer` needs to be initialized to 0 to allow `customer<-customer+1` and then the `if(length(customer)==0)` is useless beceause always FALSE.

Comment: @Prolix Thanks for your kind correction. I manage to solve the problem.